# Hide namespace in Quick Info from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to hide the clumsy and verbose namespace expression from the Quick Info of classes in VS?

I don't want this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the class names displayed a bit cleaner like this? It is plain unreadable for the moment. I am thinking of some plugins like ReSharper, CodeRush, JustCode etc.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want this? Yes, the namespace information seems superfluous for BCL types that you know anyway. However, I'm currently working on a large project with thousands of classes spread across several dozen solutions. Regularly, I find myself cursing VS for *not* always displaying the fully qualified type names.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you're right, one would want it at times. The best option is to have the choice..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Further information requested

Could you please *confirm* which version (and any updates) of Visual Studio you are using? I do see Visual Sudio 2013 as a tag in your question.

Also, is it possible to provide a screenshot of the code without the *Quick Info* displayed, but, highlight the exact location in your code that you were trying to display *Quick Info* for?

### Initial Answer

As mentioned elsewhere, Resharper can be used to enhance intellisense. i.e. one can choose whether or not to use the default Visual Studio, or Resharper, intellisense provider. But, while Resharper enhances syntax completion and display of parameters, this does not affect *Quick Info*, in the example given in the question. *Quick Info* is a tooltip, that by default, is displayed automatically when mousing over a symbol or variable.

In **Visual Studio 2010**, it was possible to write an extension to override intellisense, to display your own custom tooltip.

[IntellisensePresenter](http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntelliSense%20Presenter)

In **Visual Studio 2013**, there is no *built in* option to allow customisation.

Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, with Update 4, without Resharper:

[image: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4]

Displays the following *Quick Info* for a Generic Dictionary:

[image: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4 Quick Info]

In **Visual Studio 2015** (currently Release Candidate), the intellisense tooltip for *Quick Info* is altered, with increased readability:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense]

### Expansion of Answer

Revisiting the example given in the question, and using a simple line of code as a test with a Dictionary containing another Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dict;
```

In Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Update 4, *with or without* Resharper latest, the following is displayed:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Update 4, with Resharper]

In Visual Studio 2015 RC, *with or without* Resharper latest, the following is displayed:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 RC, with Resharper]

**Note that Visual Studio 2015 has changed the way that *Quick Info* is displayed, and is close to the desired outcome. In this instance, ReSharper, although an excellent tool, does not affect *Quick Info*.**

### Updates following comments

***Visual Studio 2015 RC Quick Info behaviour***

To validate that custom types exhibit the same behaviour as described above in Visual Studio 2015 RC, a simple class is created, in a new namespace:

```
namespace StackAnswer
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int MyProperty
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

Referencing the type using its 'fully qualified' name (i.e without a using statement):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, StackAnswer.MyClass>> dict;
```

Displays the following:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Other Namespace]

Adding a using statement:

```
using StackAnswer;
```

And altering the reference to the type to not be 'fully qualified':

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MyClass>> dict;
```

Indicates that Visual Studio 2015 RC displays the name according to the reference declaration:

[image]

This is *possibly* behaviour allowed by use of the Rosyln compiler.

***Resharper's "Quick Documentation"***

If using Resharper's "Quick Documentation" feature that is opened via a key combination (which is **not** Visual Studio *Quick Info* that is displayed on mouse over, as mentioned in the question), the namespaces are indeed shortened. Two screenshots below taken in Visual Studio 2013:

[image: Type Quick Documentation]

[image: Local Variable Quick Documentation]

***Additional note: background information regarding Quick Info***

[Visual Assist](http://wholetomato.com/default.asp), an extension for Visual Studio, does possess the ability to enhance, and potentially replace the *Quick Info* tooltip - *if* built-in *Quick Info* is turned off.

[Quick Info in Visual Assist](http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W206)

**However**, currently, in Visual Studio (up to and including 2015 RC), the ability to turn off the built in *Quick Info* is only available for the C/C++ language; therefore it is unlikely that any tool will presently be able to achieve the exact desired behaviour as mentioned in the original question, which is related to the C# language.

(If using C/C++ this can be found via Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced >Auto Quick Info.)

Comment: Thanks for the research you have done. It's nice to see VS 2015 bringing that change. I am a little worried if the change is only for primitive types for which C# has aliases, likes `string`, `int` etc. Worried if I would again see `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` in next version too.

Comment: It is indeed when I place the cursor on a class that I get that Quick Info. For eg, if I write `var dict = .....ToDictionary(...);` and I place cursor on `var` keyword it pops up as I have shown in my question. Another annoyance is when cursor is placed on method names in the code, especially generic methods.

Comment: Your second update was more helpful in this regard, ie, addresses my concern in comment 1. Cant thank enough. Btw it's not true ReSharper doesnt help. It does. See the other answer.

Comment: @nawful - I have updated my answer with a better example, that is closer to what you are attempting. Visual Studio 2015 is not displaying the full namespace. ReSharper does enhance Code Completion - but, this is a different thing to Quick Info, hence my use of italics in my answer.

Comment: Mc, to display the Quick Info, in resharper you have to press Ctrl+Q. See https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html

Comment: I know - actually you can choose to use different key mappings - in mine, for example, it is actually Ctrl-Shift-F1. Agreed this does display a shortened type, e.g. without a full namespace, but this is not Quick Info as per your question.

Comment: I have updated the answer with screenshots of the Quick Documentation feature in Resharper (Visual Studio 2013, Resharper 9.1). It is for you to decide if this is a solution to your problem...

Comment: If you edit your answer one more time, the answer turns itself into community wiki and you wont gain anymore reputation for your hard work :)

Comment: So I evaluated both products, ie VS 2013 default Quick Info (Ctrl + K + I) and ReSharper Quick Documentation (Ctrl+Shift+F1) and I have a smile on my face now to realise how different the two are. VS default one is simpler and much easier on eyes, while ReSharper one aims to be a mini documentation itself with clickable links etc (hardly readable). The irony is that it is ReSharper's feature which answers my question, ie, it never displays the namespace along with the class name, be it on class definitions or method names, exactly what I was looking for. Hardly readable, so I stick with VS.

Comment: Btw, Quick Info isn't displayed solely when you mouse hover over symbols, it's also displayed manually by pressing keyboard shortcut. I have not talked about mouse hovering in my question. I'm in two minds now. Should I accept Max's answer which straightforward answers my question or should I accept yours for letting me know of a solution I like better? I think I will go with yours, for being more comprehensive :) Once again, thanks.

Comment: @nawfal - Quick Info is indeed accessible via a keyboard shortcut, but its tooltip cannot be disabled in Visual Studio for any language other than C/C++, so, it is basically an 'always on' tooltip feature for C#, etc. I mention that in my answer as 'additional information'. Personally although the reputation is nice to have, I am more interested in 'getting it right', so if I come across more information I will keep this up to date. I will be evaluating other tools (hence adding Visual Assist to my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for that. You can adjust the Parameter Info and Quick Info using the [Parameter Info](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Parameter_Info) and [Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Quick_Documentation) features respectively. Both by default hides namespaces and offer more fine grained control over what to display.

On the website you can download a 30 day demo.

Comment: I can't upvote or accept this without more details. Can u tell me where in resharper is the feature?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html  - Parameter Info and point -Quick Documentation. There is also a good video: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/ or go to  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Customization+Guide

Comment: Max, thanks for backing it up. I am not the downvoter, but I can understand why he did that. Always add relevant information to the answer, otherwise you're merely asking the OP to go through the entire documentation. For now I will edit your answer. +1

Comment: Upvoted as I believe the Quick Documentation feature of Resharper is relevant to the original question, and may be a solution for others.

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 10, you can add a [global using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) for `System.Collections.Generic` for instance.
This will hide this namespace displayed in quick info.